# Is the new session variable automatically replaced with the old one when put the the session again with the same name?

Tags: java, jsf, session, web-applications, session-variables

Let's say I create a Customer variable and put it into my sesssion by:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getSessionMap().put("currentUser", currentUser);
```

Then, let us say that I made some changes on this object. I first get the Customer object from the session, make some changes on it by the following way:

```
//Do the changes, set username again etc.
Customer currentCustomer = (Customer)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("currentCustomer");
```

Then, if I put this new customer object to the session with the same name as it was before, is it replaced with the old one? I mean, if I write following code after updating that object, is the session variable updated:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getSessionMap().put("currentCustomer", currentCustomer);
```

I mean, I had put a variable called "currentCustomer" into the session, I updated it and put again into the session with the same name "currentCustomer". What happens in this case? Is it automatically replaces with the old one? Because I think we cannot put two different objects into the session with the same names right?

Comment: Since this code is related to JSF application, I would first ask **why** would you need to manually saving something in session instead of using a `@SessionScoped` managed bean. Note that three people already give you an answer of the problem but looks like you could have a design issue.

Comment: Your question is back to front. The *old* value is replaced by the *new* one, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do the third step because the currentCustomer is the same object instance. That is, after the second step the map still has currentCustomer instance that the one you just get out of it with get(key), and if you get that instance and change some values inside it, the map will have all the changes because is still the same instance.

If you somehow need to use another instance of the currentCustomer then yes you need to do a put("currentCustomer", currentCustomer); to your map again.

Comment: ah you're right i edited and made changes first then created new object in the question

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, yes. The value will be replaced with the new one, because it's a `java.util.Map`, which stores values, and associates them with a key.

As long as your key is `"currentCustomer"`, any object can be associated to this.